# Can I use \input inside an \include?

Tags: input, include, nesting

I know it is not possible to nest one `\include` inside another, but what about `\input`?  Is it possible to have something like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\include{file1}

\end{document}
```

and then in `file1.tex`:

```
\section{samplesection}
\input{file2}
```

in `file2.tex`;

```
\section{samplesection2}
Hello
```

Comment: Did you try to do this?

Comment: I did, and it worked, but I wanted to know if it was because of luck (or such a small example) and if I was going to have any problems in the future for using it this way

Comment: You can nest \input{macros} and You can't nest \include{files} files. See ["When should I use \input vs. \include?" : Martin Scharrer Answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32058)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quoting Kopka and Daly, *Guide to LaTeX*, 4th edition (2004), p. 207:

> `\include` commands may not be nested: They may only appear in the
>   main processing file. However, an `\input` command may be given within
>   a file that is `\include`d.